Pandas - calculate time series delta from at least 2 days ago
For every row in a pandas dataframe, I want to calculate: what's the fraction change from the row that's at least n (say 2) days ago. I want to implement this using shift() rather than for loops. Example below:
            x   change
Date        
2024-04-01  1   0.00000
2024-04-05  2   1.00000 # (2-1) / 1
2024-04-06  3   2.00000 # (3 - 1) / 1
2024-04-07  4   1.00000 # (4 - 2) / 2
2024-04-08  5   0.66666 # (5 - 3) / 3
2024-04-09  6   0.50000 # (6 - 4) / 4


"fraction change from the row that's at least n (say 2) days ago". So, why do you have (2-1) / 1 in the second row? That's only 1 day ago.

No, that's 4 days ago: note the first row is 1 April, 2nd row is 5th April.

Of course, overlooked that one. Sorry

Here's one approach:

Select column 'x', pass a complete date range (using pd.date_range) to df.reindex and apply df.ffill to fill gaps.
Now, use df.pipe to apply the function with df.shift, and chain df.loc to get back only the original df.index values.
Assign the result to a new column 'change' with df.assign.

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df = df.assign(
    change=df['x']
    .reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max()))
    .ffill()
    .pipe(lambda s: (s - s.shift(2)) / s.shift(2))
    .loc[df.index]
)

Output:
            x    change
2024-04-01  1       NaN
2024-04-05  2  1.000000
2024-04-06  3  2.000000
2024-04-07  4  1.000000
2024-04-08  5  0.666667
2024-04-09  6  0.500000


You should mention that this creates a row for all missing days. This might be inconvenient if you have large jumps (e.g. a few years missing) or if you want to change the logic to a different step (e.g. 5 min instead of 2 days). Pandas nicely handles datetime frequencies, better take advantage of it ;)

You can use a merge_asof and shift:
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

x2 = pd.merge_asof(df[[]], df[['x']].shift(freq='2D'),
                   left_index=True, right_index=True,
                   direction='backward'
                  )['x'].reindex(df.index)

df['change'] = (df['x']-x2)/x2

Output:
            x    change
Date                   
2024-04-01  1       NaN
2024-04-05  2  1.000000
2024-04-06  3  2.000000
2024-04-07  4  1.000000
2024-04-08  5  0.666667
2024-04-09  6  0.500000


Note that the index should be sorted

what does [[]] do in df[[]], is that copying and creating a completely new dataframe as a temporary object?

@Baron this is just to get a Dataframe without any column (just the index) as no more is needed for the merge_asof. You could use merge_asof(df, df.shift(freq='2D'), ...)['x_y'] instead but this handles more columns unnecessarily ;)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {
    'Date': ['1990-04-01', '1990-04-05', '1990-04-06', '1990-04-07', '1990-04-08', '1990-04-09'],
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}

# Convert 'Date' to datetime and set as index
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(pd.to_datetime(data['Date']))
print(df)
"""
                  Date  x
1990-04-01  1990-04-01  1
1990-04-05  1990-04-05  2
1990-04-06  1990-04-06  3
1990-04-07  1990-04-07  4
1990-04-08  1990-04-08  5
1990-04-09  1990-04-09  6
"""
# Calculate fractional change with n=2 
n = 2

shifted_x = df['x'].shift(n).bfill()
print('shifted_x :')
print(shifted_x)
"""
shifted_x :
1990-04-01    1.0
1990-04-05    1.0
1990-04-06    1.0
1990-04-07    2.0
1990-04-08    3.0
1990-04-09    4.0
Name: x, dtype: float64
"""
df['change1'] = np.where(shifted_x.notna(), (df['x'] - shifted_x) / shifted_x, np.nan)
#OR
df['change2'] = (df['x'] - shifted_x) / shifted_x.fillna(method='ffill')

print(df)
"""
                Date  x   change1   change2
1990-04-01  1990-04-01  1  0.000000  0.000000
1990-04-05  1990-04-05  2  1.000000  1.000000
1990-04-06  1990-04-06  3  2.000000  2.000000
1990-04-07  1990-04-07  4  1.000000  1.000000
1990-04-08  1990-04-08  5  0.666667  0.666667
1990-04-09  1990-04-09  6  0.500000  0.500000

"""

